# Using GCC in rtools42 to compile C files struggle

Tags: r, gcc, rtools

I'm extremely stumped.

Long story short, I can no longer use a commonly used code by our group to make simulations using rtools to compile in C (to make computation time much faster). It worked forever, but now that I am using a newer laptop with the newest Rtools (rtools42), I absolutely cannot get it to work at all. I am not totally confident about the inner workings of the old code, which makes it difficult for me to know how to update it properly.

A lot about the rtools directory has changed since we used this code. The original code, which was used with Rtools ver. 3.4.0.1964:

```
rtools <- "C:\\Rtools\\bin"
gcc <- "C:\\Rtools\\gcc-4.6.3\\bin"
path <- strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ";")[[1]]
new_path <- c(rtools, gcc, path)
new_path <- new_path[!duplicated(tolower(new_path))]
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(new_path, collapse = ";"))

# Working directory (put .c file and parameters file here)
setwd("C:/Users/test")

# compile my model from C definition
dyn.unload("C:/Users/test/Model.dll") # unload dll
system("C:/Users/test/R CMD SHLIB Model.c")
dyn.load("C:/Users/test/Model.dll") # Load dll
```

I have made it far enough to realize that the `rtools` and `gcc` object lines are likely the source of all the problems, since rtools42 has significantly different directory paths than Rtools did. I have tried to change these lines of code. I think the `rtools` object is right now, but I don't think I'm correctly loading the GCC. I searched in my rtools42 folder for gcc.exe, and I have 2 files, but neither path works...

Any insight? Thanks.

```
rtools <- "C:\\rtools42\\usr\\bin"
gcc <- "C:\\rtools42\\x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix\\bin"
path <- strsplit(Sys.getenv("PATH"), ";")[[1]]
new_path <- c(rtools, gcc, path)
new_path <- new_path[!duplicated(tolower(new_path))]
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(new_path, collapse = ";"))

# compile my model from C definition
dyn.unload("C:/Users/test/Model.dll") # unload dll
system("C:/Users/test/R CMD SHLIB Model.c")
dyn.load("C:/Users/test/Model.dll") # Load dll
```

where I get this error when I try to load the .dll:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/test/Model.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```